# Issue with delete branch

Tags: git

I have commit with tag "1"

```
 git tag "1" <SHA-of-the-commit>
```

I also have branch with name "1"

```
git checkout -b "1"
```

When I delete the branch "1" first the tag was delete and in the second operation the branch was deleted.

```
git branch -D 1
```

Is it ok ?
Can i choose if to delete branch or tag ?

Comment: Can't reproduce it on my machine - it always deletes the branch "1" and not the tag. What does your environment look like? (Win/Linux/Mac - git version)

Comment: I am using jgit and and not git bash it was just an example.

Comment: I saw that jgit have his logic to get the the getRef . it look on [, refs/, refs/tags/, refs/heads/, refs/remotes/] and then try to find the right result so if we have tag and branch it first delete the tag and then the branch

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jgit, you should still be able to delete a tag by using the irght *tag* API, as illustrated in [`tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api/TagCommandTest.java`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api/TagCommandTest.java#L141-L152):

```java
        git.commit().setMessage("initial commit").call();
        Ref tagRef = git.tag().setName("tag").call();
        assertEquals(1, db.getTags().size());

        List<String> deleted = git.tagDelete().setTags(tagRef.getName())
                .call();
        assertEquals(1, deleted.size());
        assertEquals(tagRef.getName(), deleted.get(0));
        assertEquals(0, db.getTags().size());

        Ref tagRef1 = git.tag().setName("tag1").call();
        Ref tagRef2 = git.tag().setName("tag2").call();
        assertEquals(2, db.getTags().size());
        deleted = git.tagDelete().setTags(tagRef1.getName(), tagRef2.getName())
                .call();
        assertEquals(2, deleted.size());
        assertEquals(0, db.getTags().size());
```

That should delete the tag "`1`" only, not the branch named "`1`".

Same thing for deleting a branch ([using the right API](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api/BranchCommandTest.java#L288-L290)):

```java
public void testDelete() throws Exception {
    createBranch(git, "ForDelete", false, "master", null);
    git.branchDelete().setBranchNames("ForDelete").call();
```

Comment: Tיhe problem that I don't want to delete tag but I want to delete branch when I call to the API of delete branch first it tried to delete tag if it succeed it didn't try to delete branch  the logic is on DeleteBranchCommand call method repo.getRef(branchName);